# If last names are similar in [Name] column, fill in missing values of another column

Tags: pandas, iteration

Below is a sample of a much larger dataframe.

```
       Fare      Cabin  Pclass  Ticket  Name
257     86.5000     B77     1   110152  Cherry, Miss. Gladys
759     86.5000     B77     1   110152  Rothes, the Countess. of (Lucy Noel Martha Dye...
504     86.5000     B79     1   110152  Maioni, Miss. Roberta
262     79.6500     E67     1   110413  Taussig, Mr. Emil
558     79.6500     E67     1   110413  Taussig, Mrs. Emil (Tillie Mandelbaum)
585     79.6500     NaN     1   110413  Taussig, Miss. Ruth
475     52.0000     A14     1   110465  Clifford, Mr. George Quincy
110     52.0000     C110    1   110465  Porter, Mr. Walter Chamberlain
335     26.0000     C106    1   110469  Maguire, Mr. John Edward
158     26.5500     D22     1   110489  Borebank, Mr. John James
430     26.5500     C52     1   110564  Bjornstrom-Steffansson, Mr. Mauritz Hakan
236     75.2500     D37     1   110813  Warren, Mr. Frank Manley
366     75.2500     D37     1   110813  Warren, Mrs. Frank Manley (Anna Sophia Atkinson)
191     26.0000     NaN     1   111163  Salomon, Mr. Abraham L
170     33.5000     B19     1   111240  Van der hoef, Mr. Wyckoff
462     38.5000     E63     1   111320  Gee, Mr. Arthur H
329     57.9792     Nan     1   111361  Hippach, Miss. Jean Gertrude
523     57.9792     B18     1   111361  Hippach, Mrs. Louis Albert (Ida Sophia Fischer)
```

If I want to iterate the filling of missing values of "Cabin" for people who are missing "Cabin" values, with someone else's "Cabin" values, only if

the someone else (the one who has a cabin value) has the same last name and also are in the vicinity of oneself( as  in one above or one below them) .

So in the dataframe above, [Tassuig, Miss.Ruth]'s Cabin value of "Nan" would be replaced with that of [Tassuig, Mrs.Emil]'s cabin value [E67] who is one above herself because both conditions are met. (Same last name and in the vicinity)

And  [Hippach, Miss. Jean Gertrude]'s missing cabin value would be replaced with
[ Hippach, Mrs. Louis Albert (Ida Sophia Fischer)]'s Cabin value of [B18].

I tried to think of iteration but this is as far as I got

```
for x in df.Name.str.split(',')[x][0] ==df.Name.str.split(',')[x+1][0]:
    if df.Cabin[x] or df.Cabin[x+1] == np.nan:
      df.Cabin.replace(np.nan,
```

I want to make sure the np.nan value is replaced with a True value and not np.nan. Couldn't figure out how to do that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`groupby` + `fillna`

```
# back fills, then forward fills
def bffill(x):
    return x.bfill().ffill()

# group by last name
df['Cabin'] = df.groupby(df.Name.str.split(',').str[0]).Cabin.apply(bffill)

df
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice solution

Comment: @BobHaffner ty, yours as well.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. So this code, groups all the similar last names via groupby, and then performs the function bffill on each group's Cabin's elements? So this will ensure that all Cabin elements are the same within each group. Am I understanding this correctly?

Answer (score 3):

Starting with your DataFrame

```
print(df)    
       Fare     Cabin  Pclass  Ticket  \
    0   86.5000       B77       1  110152   
    1   86.5000       B77       1  110152   
    2   86.5000       B79       1  110152   
    3   79.6500       E67       1  110413   
    4   79.6500       E67       1  110413   
    5   79.6500       NaN       1  110413   
    6   52.0000       A14       1  110465   
    7   52.0000      C110       1  110465   
    8   26.0000      C106       1  110469   
    9   26.5500       D22       1  110489   
    10  26.5500       C52       1  110564   
    11  75.2500       D37       1  110813   
    12  75.2500       D37       1  110813   
    13  26.0000       NaN       1  111163   
    14  33.5000       B19       1  111240   
    15  38.5000       E63       1  111320   
    16  57.9792       NaN       1  111361   
    17  57.9792       B18       1  111361   

                                                     Name  
    0                                Cherry, Miss. Gladys  
    1   Rothes, the Countess. of (Lucy Noel Martha Dye...  
    2                               Maioni, Miss. Roberta  
    3                                   Taussig, Mr. Emil  
    4              Taussig, Mrs. Emil (Tillie Mandelbaum)  
    5                                 Taussig, Miss. Ruth  
    6                         Clifford, Mr. George Quincy  
    7                      Porter, Mr. Walter Chamberlain  
    8                            Maguire, Mr. John Edward  
    9                            Borebank, Mr. John James  
    10          Bjornstrom-Steffansson, Mr. Mauritz Hakan  
    11                           Warren, Mr. Frank Manley  
    12   Warren, Mrs. Frank Manley (Anna Sophia Atkinson)  
    13                             Salomon, Mr. Abraham L  
    14                          Van der hoef, Mr. Wyckoff  
    15                                  Gee, Mr. Arthur H  
    16                       Hippach, Miss. Jean Gertrude  
    17    Hippach, Mrs. Louis Albert (Ida Sophia Fischer)
```

Creating a new column/series with just the LastName.  Note, might be a better way to do this with pandas str methods, but I couldn't get anything to work

```
df['LastName'] = df['Name'].map(lambda x : x[:x.find(',')])
```

Then we leverage Pandas' [shift](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html) and boolean indexing to see if the passenger above has the same last name (ie the Taussig case)

```
    filter = (df['Cabin'].isnull()) & (df['LastName'] == df['LastName'].shift())
    df.loc[filter,'Cabin'] = df['Cabin'].shift()
```

and then the passenger below by passing a -1 to shift() (ie the Hippach case)

```
filter = (df['Cabin'].isnull()) & (df['LastName'] == df['LastName'].shift(-1))
df.loc[filter,'Cabin'] = df['Cabin'].shift(-1)

print(df)
       Fare     Cabin  Pclass  Ticket  \
0   86.5000       B77       1  110152   
1   86.5000       B77       1  110152   
2   86.5000       B79       1  110152   
3   79.6500       E67       1  110413   
4   79.6500       E67       1  110413   
5   79.6500       E67       1  110413   
6   52.0000       A14       1  110465   
7   52.0000      C110       1  110465   
8   26.0000      C106       1  110469   
9   26.5500       D22       1  110489   
10  26.5500       C52       1  110564   
11  75.2500       D37       1  110813   
12  75.2500       D37       1  110813   
13  26.0000       NaN       1  111163   
14  33.5000       B19       1  111240   
15  38.5000       E63       1  111320   
16  57.9792       B18       1  111361   
17  57.9792       B18       1  111361   

                                                 Name                LastName  
0                                Cherry, Miss. Gladys                  Cherry  
1   Rothes, the Countess. of (Lucy Noel Martha Dye...                  Rothes  
2                               Maioni, Miss. Roberta                  Maioni  
3                                   Taussig, Mr. Emil                 Taussig  
4              Taussig, Mrs. Emil (Tillie Mandelbaum)                 Taussig  
5                                 Taussig, Miss. Ruth                 Taussig  
6                         Clifford, Mr. George Quincy                Clifford  
7                      Porter, Mr. Walter Chamberlain                  Porter  
8                            Maguire, Mr. John Edward                 Maguire  
9                            Borebank, Mr. John James                Borebank  
10          Bjornstrom-Steffansson, Mr. Mauritz Hakan  Bjornstrom-Steffansson  
11                           Warren, Mr. Frank Manley                  Warren  
12   Warren, Mrs. Frank Manley (Anna Sophia Atkinson)                  Warren  
13                             Salomon, Mr. Abraham L                 Salomon  
14                          Van der hoef, Mr. Wyckoff            Van der hoef  
15                                  Gee, Mr. Arthur H                     Gee  
16                       Hippach, Miss. Jean Gertrude                 Hippach  
17    Hippach, Mrs. Louis Albert (Ida Sophia Fischer)                 Hippach
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm having trouble understanding this part of the lambda function:  x[:x.find(',')]). I can't understand how this is able to separate the name.

Comment: x is a str so we can use str methods like find().  find(',') locates the first occurrence of a comma and returns its position within x.  That position(int) is used to slice x/name.  Make sense?    p.s. I would go with piRsquared's solution

Comment: Ah! The [] are used to slice the string. I thought x[] was referring to the dataframe. Thank you for the explanation. Yeah, I plan to look at piRsquared's code once I understand you code.

Comment: I finally understand you code. It was a little complicated but ingenious at the same time. I learned a lot. Thank you for taking the time to write out the code.